# Sharing a page with specific result shows no data

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to make multiple pages with the name of users which will then be shared with each them. However, once I tested it by adding one of them, they managed to get to the page, but no results are shown when clicking at the button for pulling the data from the Drive Sheet. The circle is doing a single circle and that's it - no data, only the headers are shown.

Is it required for the users to have the file shared with them in Drive in order to pull it on Google App Maker or is there any security setting that I have to adjust?

**Settings in the publish menu**:
[image: Settings in the publish menu]

**User roles in Security in the PAGE and DATA**:
[image: User roles in Security in the PAGE and DATA]

There are no errors in the Developer or Preview tab.

Comment: I would like to help you better but the information provided so far is not helpful; Plus, I think the approach you are using is not the best one.

Comment: I am new to Appmaker and have next to zero knowledge about building apps in general.

The idea is that we have 25 employees where we want them to have a place to track the accounts they work with. Each one of them has to see only their accounts and not of their colleagues.

I was thinking about having 25 separate Data Sheets for each one of them and separate Page shared which will be visibly only for them.

If there are better ways to achieve that - I am happy to learn how this could be done.

If you see specific info missing which should be noted, let me know.

Comment: If you are running the app as the developer then google is using your credentials to access the sheet. If you are running the app as the user then it’s using the user credentials to access the sheet and the user would need access to the sheet as well. Why are you using sheets to pull data vs a drive table inside app maker and then just using the built in security settings to limit access to each user’s data?

Comment: Because the data is putted in a sheet in Drive where only the Admins want to see everything in that particular sheet. I haven't figured another way to have all data in 1 sheet and give the employees access only for the accounts assigned to them. I've tried with simple =IMPORTRANGE in separate sheets shared only with them, but it seems the formula has a hidden limit (20 or so), so I was exploring another ways trough Appmaker.

Answer (score 1):

If you go down with Spreadsheet approach, then you'll face with implementing CRUD operations almost from scratch, what is opposite from the App Maker mission.

> only the Admins want to see everything

Out of the box deployment Admins can see all data

> employees access only for the accounts assigned to them

You can achieve such security configuration by adding `Owner` field to your model ([Record Permissions](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/security/secure-app-data#secure_operations_on_records)).

Take a look at [App Maker Templates](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/), there are lots permission configuration samples.